# Cache Issues with Express.js 4.0 in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, express

I've generated a brand new *express.js* app with the `express-generator`but when I'm trying to do some changes, nothing is taking in consideration while reloading in the browser.

I've tried everything we can find on the internet.

- Disable Chrome Cache (with dev inspector or CMD + MAJ + PR0N)
- Use `app.disable('etag');`

I'm running the server with the given command-line `DEBUG=testApp:* ./bin/www`

And here's what the console give me when I'm accessing the `localhost:3000` :

```
GET / 200 7.885 ms - 179
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 10.014 ms - -
```

Thanks in advance for helping, I'm sure it will help alot of people.

**EDIT :** After doing some experimentations, the `.jade`files are not cached but all the functional stuff like `routes`and `node.js` part aren't reloading.

Comment: And what happens when you restart the app, does the changes take effect then ?

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't precise that but yes, when I restart the app, changes are here.

Comment: Node caches the app for you, not the external files, the templates etc, but all the routes and functional stuff is loaded into memory, where it decides if requires are needed or the module is already loaded etc. The solution is to restart the app when you've made changes to those files.

Comment: you can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) for reloading you node app when files are changed

Comment: Awh I see, it's weird I though it was like any others server like you just have to reload for seeing changes without using a third party plugin (except if you want live reload ..) But thank you through, post it as an answer, I'll upvote you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer made by adeneo in comments on the first thread.

It was just because Node.JS application need a restart from the server for taking in consideration modifications made on .js files.

[nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) reload the server each time a save on .js files has been detected.